# Делать подзагрузку при наведении через время

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такой скрипт.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $DivMoreFnds = $('.icon-more-frnd-prof');
    $ContentMore = $('#moreajax-frnds');

$DivMoreFnds.mouseover(function(){
$.ajax({
url: '../friends/more_friends.php',
cache: false,
beforeSend: function() {
$ContentMore.fadeIn(0);
},
success: function(html){
$ContentMore.html(html);
}
});
return false;
});

$DivMoreFnds.mouseover(function() {
var active = $(this).attr('data-active');
if(active == 1) {
 $ContentMore.fadeOut(0);
 $(this).attr('data-active', '0');
} //Если было свернуто, разварачиваем
else {
 $ContentMore.show();
 $(this).attr('data-active', '1');
}
});
$ContentMore.mouseup(function() {return false });
//для кнопки
$DivMoreFnds.mouseup(function() {return false });
//для всей страницы
$(document).mouseup(function() {$ContentMore.hide(); $DivMoreFnds.attr('data-active', ''); });
});
```

Помогите сделать, пожалуйста, чтобы при наведении через, например, секунду только шла подзагрузка и чтобы при бездействии, например, если человек отвел на другой любой элемент, скрывалось через ту же секунду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Помогите сделать пожалуйста чтобы при
> наведение через например секунду
> только шла под загрузка и чтобы при
> бездействия например если человек
> отвел на другой любой элемент
> скрывалось через ту же секунду.

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, используйте **setInterval()**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $DivMoreFnds = $('.icon-more-frnd-prof');
        $ContentMore = $('#moreajax-frnds');

        $DivMoreFnds.mouseover(function () {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../friends/more_friends.php',
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $ContentMore.fadeIn(0);
                    },
                    success: function (html) {
                        $ContentMore.html(html);
                    }
                });

                var active = $(this).attr('data-active');
                if (active == 1) {
                    $ContentMore.fadeOut(0);
                    $(this).attr('data-active', '0');
                } //Если было свернуто, разварачиваем
                else {
                    $ContentMore.show();
                    $(this).attr('data-active', '1');
                }
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });

        $ContentMore.mouseup(function () {
            return false
        });
//для кнопки
        $DivMoreFnds.mouseup(function () {
            return false
        });
//для всей страницы
        $(document).mouseup(function () {
            $ContentMore.hide();
            $DivMoreFnds.attr('data-active', '');
        });
    });
```

Comment: @erbolking, только теперь он у меня не закрывается. Я просто еще плохо знаю jquery, ajax. Знаю то, что делается через setinterval. Помогите, пожалуйста, оно теперь открывает с задержкой, но блок теперь не закрывается.

Comment: Обновил ответ. В таком случае, единственное, что могу вам посоветовать - ознакомится с основами jQuery http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: @erbolking, спасибо большое вам. Да, буду изучать.